# How to use best estimator from pipeline to predict test set?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, xgboost

I developed a pipeline using `XGBoost` which returned me a best estimator.
However, trying to use this best estimator to predict my test set the following error is raised: `"ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames"`.

Below is my code for the pipeline that I have used:
Note: `ct` is just `ColumnTransformer` using `SimpleImputer` and `OneHotEncoder` for categorical columns and `SimpleImputer` and `StandardScaler` for numerical columns

```py
ml_step_1 = ('transform', ct)
ml_step_2 = ('pca', PCA())
xgb = ('xgb', XGBRegressor())
xgb_pipe = Pipeline([ml_step_1, ml_step_2, xgb])
xgb = RandomizedSearchCV(xgb_pipe, xgb_param_grid, cv=kf, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error');
xgb.fit(train_full_features, train_full_target);
```

Running the following pipeline, here is the best estimator that I got:

```py
Best XGBoost parameters: {'xgb__silent': True, 'xgb__n_estimators': 1000, 'xgb__max_depth': 4, 'xgb__learning_rate': 0.09999999999999999, 'transform__num__imputer__strategy': 'median', 'transform__cat__imputer__strategy': 'most_frequent', 'pca__n_components': 68}
```

Now, I called this best estimator and did the following:

```py
test_full_imp = pd.DataFrame(xgb.best_estimator_.named_steps['transform'].transform(test_full))
test_final = xgb.best_estimator_.named_steps['pca'].transform(test_full_imp)
predictions = xgb.best_estimator_.predict(test_final)
```

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of trials, I figured out what was wrong:
Just type:

```py
xgb._best_estimator_.named_steps['xgb'].predict(test_final)
```